# display json type data in a blade

Tags: php, json, laravel

display json type data in a blade
I have a table in my DB where I store data and one of those data is of the json type, and everything goes well for me, but the problem starts when I want to display those json in a blade
this is my json data type
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

where in my blade I make the query with php that all the data that has the same id of an order is extracted and displayed but I want to display the json data where I do this foreach

```xml
<div class="modal-body">
    <?php
    $order[] = $ord_com->id;
    $tareasco = DB::table('tareas')->whereIn('orden_compra_id',$order)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
    ?> 
    @foreach($tareasco as $audi)
        {{ $audi->componente_id }}<!--here it shows me everything ok-->
        @if (is_array($audi->componente_id) || is_object($audi->componente_id))
            @foreach ($audi->componente_id as $documen)
                <h1>{{$documen['partidas_id']}}</h1>
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

in the second foreach where I want to show the json data does not show me any data

EDIT:

in the second foreach where I want to show the json data does not show me any data y creo que es porque llamo mal los datos porque al hacer lo recomendado no me muestra nada

```
[{"id": 9913, "cantidad": "12", "costoini": "12", "partidas_id": "1", "servicios_id": "1077", "componente_id": "1", "sub_componente_id": "1", "sub_sub_componentes_id": "1"}] [{"id": 2548, "cantidad": "2", "costoini": "123", "partidas_id": "1", "servicios_id": "1077", "componente_id": "1", "sub_componente_id": "1", "sub_sub_componentes_id": "1"}, {"id": 7555, "cantidad": "4", "costoini": "124", "partidas_id": "2", "servicios_id": "1078", "componente_id": "1", "sub_componente_id": "1", "sub_sub_componentes_id": "1"}]
```

Comment: You probably need to decode the json with `json_decode` before you can do anything useful with it. Before that, it's just a string.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either use `json_decode` to turn that json array into an array of arrays (`json_decode($json, true)`) or an array of objects (`json_decode($json)`)

```xml
@php($tareasco = DB::table('tareas')->whereIn('orden_compra_id',$order)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get())
@foreach($tareasco as $audi)
    @php($componente_id = json_decode($audi->componente_id))
    @if (is_array($audi->componente_id))
        @foreach ($audi->componente_id as $documen)
            <h1>{{ $documen->partidas_id }}</h1>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

```xml
@php($tareasco = DB::table('tareas')->whereIn('orden_compra_id',$order)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get())
@foreach($tareasco as $audi)
    @php($componente_id = json_decode($audi->componente_id, true))
    @if (is_array($audi->componente_id))
        @foreach ($audi->componente_id as $documen)
            <h1>{{ $documen['partidas_id'] }}</h1>
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

A better option would be to define that behavior in the `$cast` property of an Eloquent Model.

```php
class Tarea extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'componente_id' => 'array'
    ];
}
```

```php
$tareasco = Tarea::whereIn(...)->orderBy(...)->get();
```

```xml
@foreach($tareasco as $audi)
    @if (is_array($audi->componente_id))
        @foreach($audi->componente_id as $documen)
            {{ $documen['partidas_id'] }}
        @endforeach
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but I have edited my question I would appreciate if you help me a little more

Comment: Seems like you need to do a third foreach. It would help if you wrote the string in the question instead of using an image.

Comment: I already put the json that it brings

Comment: If that the string, the problem is more complicated. It's not valid json. Missing a  `,` between `] [` , and it would need to be wrapped in an extra pair of brackets. Is every row like that?

Comment: The query that I do is that it brings me the data that has the same purchase order id. In this case, each data that it brings has its json data and when I remember to do the foreach, it joins the data in that way

Comment: The problem is the string is not valid json.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Model and that column is of type json instead of using the DB: query builder the column will be seen as an array inside Laravel (and the blade)

Then you can just treat it like a standard array.

```
@foreach($tareasco as $audi)
   <!-- your looped items -->
@endforeach
```

I find its good practice to rely on the Eloquent and Models

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access it as JSON in `foreach`, you should access it like an Object, not an array.

```
<h1>{{$documen->partidas_id}}</h1>
```

---

**For Your Information**

When we use Laravel **Framework**, we don't write fetch commands in view. like this

```
<?php
    $order[] = $ord_com->id;
    $tareasco = DB::table('tareas')->whereIn('orden_compra_id',$order)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
?>
```

We use MVC (**M**odel **V**iew **C**ontrollr ) architecture to manipulate data.